# Test results trend widget is showing as disabled in Azure devops dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, widget, dashboard

Test results trend widget is showing as disabled in Azure devops dashboard.
Now I see only test results trend advanced available.

This was working previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this this issue has been resolved, now I can see this Test results trend widget and add it to my dashboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

Now the Test results trend widget is back to normal.

Currently this is a known issue. Some users have reported the same issue on our Developer Community forum. We will report this issue to the product team and update you if there's any progress.

You can follow up on this ticket: [Test Results Trend widget disappeared](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Test-Results-Trend-widget-disappeared/1387060)

[image]
[image]

Comment: @priya Now the Test results trend widget is back to normal. Does your problem still exist?